# Regex Split - But Include new line characters - including CR LF

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have a seemingly simple situation in which I need to split a string sequence (in Java) on line breaks - but I need the new line characters included in the output (another part of the application needs these - and the original values, not just any new line character).

The code below works but CRLF (\r\n) is not included. Only one of the characters are included. This same code works if I rewrite the regex pattern to include only the \r\n characters ((?<=\r\n)), but I am unable to figure out how to capture all three of these. ((?<=\r\n)|(?<=\n)|(?<=\r)) does not work either, it still matches only the \r or \n - not both.

```
        String text = "Heres is one line\r\n" +
                "and another\r" +
                "and another one\n" +
                "all with different line ending chars";

        List<String> textLinesWithDelimiters = Arrays.asList(text.split(("((?<=\\n)|(?<=\\r))")));

        for(String ln : textLinesWithDelimiters)
        {
            // ln should include the \n, \r, or \r\n characters
            System.out.println(ln);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a *matching* approach instead:

```
String phrase = "Heres is one line\r\n" +
                "and another\r" +
                "and another one\n" +
                "all with different line ending chars";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\V+|\\v+");
Matcher m=p.matcher(phrase);
while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0).replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r"));
} // .replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r") is only for demo
```

Output:

```
Heres is one line
\r\n
and another
\r
and another one
\n
all with different line ending chars
```

See the [online Java demo](https://ideone.com/eGr4lv).

The `\\V+|\\v+` pattern matches either 1+ chars other than vertical whitespace or 1+ vertical whitespaces.